# Custom Back button in UINavigationBar subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, subclass, uinavigationitem

I'm writting a subclass of UINavigationBar, and would like to integrate in it a default backButton.

From what i understood with the documentation, I need to watch when a new item is added in the `item` property, and add my custom back button in it.

I did this  in the UINavigationBar subclass:

```
- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super pushNavigationItem:item animated:animated];

    ActionButton *leftButtom = [[ActionButton alloc] init];
    leftButtom.cancel = NO;

    [item setBackBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButtom]];
}

- (UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    return [super popNavigationItemAnimated:animated];
}
```

I don't understand why, but the `popNavigationItemAnimated` is called when I press the back button, but the `pushNavigationItem` is not called when i'm pushing a new ViewController.

I've check with the debugger and

`po [[self.navigationController navigationBar] items]`

print correctly that there is a new item on the Array.

Did i missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

please try this, I think this may help

```
// image for my back button

UIImage *backButtonImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"];
UIButton *leftBarButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];

// Setting the image for the back button

[leftBarButton setBackgroundImage: backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[leftBarButton addTarget: self action:@selector(backToMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// setting the frame for the back button

leftBarButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 32);  

// setting the custom button to navigationbars back button

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: leftBarButton];
```

Comment: You are giving me code to put in a UIViewController, i want to achieve this inside my UINavigationBar subclass. This would force me to put this code in all of my UIViewController or do a category for this and i don't fell like it is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationBar is not responsible for navigation stack. I assume that You need UINavigationController and add navigation items in view controllers pushed to navigation controller. This is a common way to organize navigation stack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But yet the UINavigationBar should be able to handle the behavior i want to have since it should be "notified" with the call that a new item is added. I just can't understand why the method is not called thought.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all I like your approach to put the responsibility of changing navigation bar to UINavigationController and not to some base UIViewController class. Kids out there seems to not understand this natural human logic. Here's a complete solution I came up with recently:

```
class NavigationControllerLightNavigationBar: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // When we load this Controller we most likely already have at least one
        // view controller to modify. So let's modify some back arrows
        for viewController in viewControllers {
            viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = createBackButton()
        }
    }

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        // Modify back arrow for every new view controller
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = createBackButton()
    }

    private func createBackButton() -> UIBarButtonItem {
        // Chose whatever size you like
        let itemHeight = CGFloat(30)
        // Make an UIImageView
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: itemHeight, height: itemHeight))
        // Make it to display icons the right way
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        // Set our icon as image
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backArrowIcon")
        // Now let's make a UIBarButton container for our image
        // and put the image inside of it
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
        // Now set this item's constraints
        barButton.width = itemHeight
        let width = barButton.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: itemHeight)
        width?.isActive = true
        let height = barButton.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: itemHeight)
        height?.isActive = true
        // Remove title
        barButton.title = nil
        // Dont forget to change your icon's color.
        // If we skip this our icon would be blue no matter what
        barButton.tintColor = UIColor.red
        return barButton
    }
}
```